# Good habits in software development - what exactly are backing services, in a general definition?

Tags: docker, web-services, service, cloud, virtual-machine

In a documentation called "The twelve factor app", I saw that the [4th factor](https://12factor.net/backing-services) was "backing services" and what I understood from it was that an ideal application must not differentiate local services from external services and this means that every single service must be an external service, accessible by an URL.

I also took a look at the fundamentals behind Docker and my main misunderstanding is: If I have an fully managed app at the same machine or VM, with microsservices architecture using Docker, where each container in isolation does what it is responsible for doing, is this app considered in 4th factor?

In other words, is container isolation considered a backing service, or it's not enough and, to be considered a backing service, the service must be in another machine outside localhost and accessible via TCP/IP?

Answer (score 1):

The important section from [The Twelve-Factor App: Backing Services](https://12factor.net/backing-services) is this (emphasis mine):

> To the app, both [local and third-party services] are attached resources, accessed via [...] **locator/credentials stored in the config**.

That is, the important part is not that that the service is "external" or that it specifically has a URL, but that you can change the location of the database at deploy time.  The example in the page is relevant: you could run a PostgreSQL database outside a container on the same host you're developing on, or in an adjacent Compose-managed container, or a Kubernetes StatefulSet+Service, or use a hosted database like Amazon RDS, but you should not need to change *code* to make this difference.

Continuing with the example of a PostgreSQL database, the standard client libraries support an environment variable `$PGHOST` that specifies the database host name (also see the [Config](https://12factor.net/config) page, environment variables tend to be easier to configure in container environments).  So you're following this practice with a Compose setup like

```yaml
version: '3.8'
services:
  database:
    image: postgres:14
  application:
    build: .
    environment:
      - PGHOST=database # <-- database host name as environment variable
```

Since this is configuration, and an environment variable, *without changing your code* you could run the same application outside a container pointing at an RDS database

```sh
export PGHOST=database.012345678901.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com
./myapp
```

What doesn't follow this pattern?  There are fairly routine questions that embed the database location directly in their code (and that's frequently `localhost`) and then try to massage the network environment to try to match their hard-coded developer setup (frequently by disabling Docker networking with `network_mode: host`).  This won't work in clustered environments like Kubernetes or if the database isn't in a container at all.

I keep harping on a database as an example here because databases are special: where containers can usually just be deleted and recreated, databases in particular have the actual data, they need to be backed up, and tasks like migrations have specific life cycles.  The database in particular is often I/O bound and can benefit from dedicated hardware under load.  It can be a good practice to run a database on bare metal or to use a hosted database solution, and then to run a cluster of completely stateless containers that call out to that external database.

Comment: Thanks a lot! you made it very clear to me. If I set up my application in a fully customizable VM like GCE (Google Compute Engine), and set up, with docker volumes to persist data, a Postgres database container under the same VM, would it be a bad practice, since VM's filesystem aren't sufficiently reliable to store data? Or there's no problem?

Comment: As always, keep good backups and practice restoring them, but that should be fine for a small application.